# how to access variable name of field

Tags: webmatrix

I have:

```
var nameOffield = "field3"; (or field4 or field6)

foreach(item in list)
{
   @item.(heare i want nameOffield)
}
```

Help.
Thanks.

Comment: Please add more information about what you want to achieve. What is a field in your case, and what is the list you're iterating over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a string indexer:

```
var nameOfField = "field3";
foreach(var item in list){
    @item[nameOfField]
}
```